# Update Using a cursor

Tags: cursors

I know that instead of cursor we can have the tables updated with different queries but I wanted to try using cursor so as to have a knowledge on cursor 
This was what I was trying I have inserted a new column which has null values instead of null I wanted to update that column based on the title column here what I used the query but I am unable to update the table can someone suggest a solution for this.

```
Declare @Title varchar(max)
Declare @Department varchar(max)

Declare Department_Cursor Cursor 
For 
    Select Title, Department 
    from Sample_table 

Open Department_Cursor
Fetch Next From Department_Cursor Into @Title, @Department

While @@fetch_status = 0
Begin
     Update sample_table
     Set @Department = 'Production' 
     where @Title = '%Production%'

     Fetch Next From Department_Cursor Into @Title, @Department
End

Close Department_Cursor 
Deallocate Department_Cursor
```

Comment: try do it like that Begin

Fetch Next From Department_Cursor
Into @Title,@Department
Update sample_table
Set @Department='Production' 
where @Title='%Production%'
End

Comment: I tried but I am unable to update the table as intended

Answer (score 1):

I tried running what you have and noticed one small error:

```
where @Title = '%Production%'
```

So if @Title ever actually = '%Production%' it will update the entire table.  Until then it's going to update 0 rows.  My guess is what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
WHERE @Title LIKE '%Production%'
  AND Title = @Title
```

And on further inspection I don't think you want this either

```
SET @Department = 'Production'
```

You probably mean

```
SET Department = 'Production'
```

Which also means you don't need to be pulling `Department` at all in your cursor.  Last but not least, since you are updating the table that the cursor is pulling from I would use a READ ONLY cursor.  This does however write the cursor results to tempdb so it may not be such a good idea if you have a large table.

Last comment: Cursors are not always bad.  But they should only be used where batch processing is not possible.  Say executing a stored procedure with multiple inputs.  I think it's great that you are being proactive and practicing them however.